# Toggle divs with mouse click

Tags: javascript

I have 15 divs which are hidden by default.They can get visible once I click every button associated with each of them and also hide them by clicking each associated button. Now what I want is that:If I click anywhere on the document other than the divs and if any of the divs already visible,it should be hidden immediately once I click outside the div and so on.I have overcome this problem by using the code below **only** if there is one div that I wish to play with.

```
function check(e){
   var target = (e && e.target);
   var obj = document.getElementById('myDiv');
   checkParent(target)?obj.style.visibility="hidden":null;
   }
function checkParent(t)
  {
          if(t==document.getElementById('myDiv'))
          {
             return false;
          }
          return true;      
  }
```

What would be the ideal solution if there are at least more than two divs that I want to manipulate the way as mentioned above?Divs are having a class say "cmnClass".I have tried this(but was in vain):

```
if(t.className!="cmnClass")
   {
     e = document.getElementsByTagName('div'); 
      for(var i=0;i<e.length;i++) 
      {
       if(e[i].className=="cmnClass") 
        e[i].style.visibility="hidden";
      } 
   }
```

A good solution is expected which is also faster

Comment: is ajax an option for you?  It would make this a bit easier and smoother on the screen.

Comment: Could you make a fiddle please?

Comment: ajax in this scenario?how,let me know? @WesHardaker

Comment: Are you using jquery? If so, you can select all DIVs with a class name and set the css to display:none.

Comment: nice idea @Poornima, are you from India?

Comment: @Poornima me too... How do I check that click is outside the divs?

Comment: If you use the same class name for all the DIVs, you can use jquery hasClass function to check if that element has a class with that name, which means that it is a DIV on which the user has clicked.

Comment: Are you allowed to use jQuery?

Comment: yeah,any idea on jquery is welcome @Dropout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use jQuery then you can assign each DIV a class which will let the script know that it's a DIV which can be toggled. This will be used for the hiding when clicked on the "background" of the container DIV.

The other part of your question could be solved by `siblings()` method, but you have to use a certain structure.

For example if your content is structured like this

```
<div id="main-container">
    <div class="element-container">
        <div class="content">Some text</div>
        <div class="button">Clickable DIV</div>
    </div>
    <div class="element-container">
        <div class="content">Some other text</div>
        <div class="button">Clickable DIV</div>
    </div>
    <div class="element-container">
        <div class="content" hidden>Third text</div>
        <div class="button">Clickable DIV</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then with proper CSS styling you can achieve the requested behavior by this jQuery code:

*Edited:*

```
$(".button").click(function(){
    $(this).siblings(".content").toggle();
});

$(document).click(function(e){
    if(!$(".element-container").is(e.target) 
        && $(".element-container").has(e.target).length === 0)
    {
        $(".content").hide();
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wC58u/)

*Requested edit:*

The triple equals sign is a strict comparator - see [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators).
So the line `$(".element-container").has(e.target).length === 0)` checks if the container which [has](http://api.jquery.com/has/) the button and the content in is [has](http://api.jquery.com/has/) also the current clicked target in it (e.target).. In this case it's compared to zero, so it returns true if it doesn't.

Comment: Please give it a try - I'm not able to test it at the moment :( If you encounter any problems feel free to ask! I'm on my way home from work, so excuse me for a bit of delay ;)

Comment: Sorry,it doesn't work, I have tested it using jQuery v1.9.0 @dropout

Comment: Thank u so much! What is $(".element-container").has(e.target).length === 0) here, can you explain to me ?

Comment: I've edited it in. Hope it's sufficient and I didn't mess up my explanation - JavaScript isn't my thing so much.. :)

Comment: It should work anyways - there are no onload events in the fiddle. Check your browser console for errors/warnings.

Comment: i mean if I copy paste the fiddle code and run in my browser then $(".button").click(function(){
    $(this).siblings(".content").toggle();
}); part doesn't work. It works with an onload event or if I wrap it within $(document).ready(function(){..}); @Dropout

Comment: If you don't wrap it inside document ready, then you have to place the script at the end of your page - making it usable after all previous code has been executed. Without the document.ready encapsulation it can only "see" the code above itself.

Comment: ehh it was as simple as it is ;) I was confused in d middle...Thanks @Dropout. Have a rocking Day...

Answer (score 1):

If you can use jquery, here's way to do it. I just created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j8sxU/1/) to demonstrate.

```
$(document).click(function (e)
{
     var element = $(".mydivclass");

   if (!element.is(e.target)
    && element.has(e.target).length === 0) 
{

    element.toggle();
}
```

});

To explain:

```
if (!element.is(e.target)
```

checks to see if it is the DIV element that is clicked and

```
element.has(e.target).length === 0
```

checks to see if there are any elements inside the DIV that were clicked.

If not, it toggles the visibility of the DIV.

You could very well set the css properties if you dont want to use toggle.

```
element.css("display","none");
```

Comment: what does .mouseup() do here? @poornima

Comment: mouseup also detects any clicks with the mouse, so I used that first to create the fiddle and later noticed that in the question, click is being used, so I just changed it.

Comment: know hindi? @Poornima

Comment: kya aap fb karti ho? agar karti ho aap se jarur baat karenge :) @poornima . magar aapko hum dhundenge kaise?